# How do you replace period to comma without an error?

Tags: iphone, xcode

I am newbie. I want to get rid of period. How do I fix this without googling, hair pulling, and errors.

> float string = [@"145,000" 
>   doubleValue] * [@".0022"
>   doubleValue];
>
> NSNumber *num=[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:string ];
>
> Money.text = [ NSString stringWithFormat:@"$ %.3f",num ];

Comment: If you're a programmer, or a wannabe programmer, who is allergic to using google and documentation -- erm, good luck with that.

Answer (score 0):

You can work around your issue by using this way:

```
[@"145,000" setString: [@"145,000"stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"," withString:@"."]];
```

or Vis Versa use it according to your need.

Comment: Yup -- a workaround, though.  Ideally, you would want to use NSNumberFormatter to properly convert between locality formatted numbers and their native C language value scalar type.